# ¿Como puedo corregir este codigo a C# nativo?

Tags: c#, cmd

Estoy trabajando en un generador de entidades que conecte al **CRM dynamic**s, tengo el siguiente código, pero al ejecutar solo me entrega la respuesta de "=> PROCESO REALIZADO CORRECTAMENTE, EL ARCHIVO SE GENERO EN EL DIRECTORIO SELECCIONADO", y enseguida me sale esto...

```
Options:
 /nologo
  Suppresses the banner. /language:<language>
  The language to use for the generated proxy code.  This can be either 'CS' or 'VB'.  The default language is 'CS'.  Short form is '/l:'.
 /url:<url>  A url or path to the SDK endpoint to contact for metadata.

 /out:<filename> The filename for the generated proxy code.  Short form is '/o:'.

 /namespace:<namespace>  The namespace for the generated proxy code.  The default namespace is the global namespace.  Short form is '/n:'.

 /username:<username>  Username to use when connecting to the server for authentication.  Short form is '/u:'.

 /password:<password>  Password to use when connecting to the server for authentication.  Short form is '/p:'.

 /domain:<domain>  Domain to authenticate against when connecting to the server.  Short form is '/d:'.

 /serviceContextName:<service context name>  The name for the generated service context. If a value is passed in, it will be used for the Service Context.  If not, no Service Context will be generated

 /help
  Show this usage message.  Short form is '/?'.

 /deviceid:<deviceid>  Device ID to use when connecting to the online server for authentication.  Short form is '/di:'.

 /devicepassword:<devicepassword>  Device Password to use when connecting to the online server for authentication.  Short form is '/dp:'.
Example:
crmsvcutil.exe /url:http://localhost/Organization1/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc /out:GeneratedCode.cs
```

Si alguien pudiese ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho, saludos cordiales.

Busco ayuda con amigos y nada, trato de indagar pero se me ha hecho difícil

```
public string Ejecutar_Dos(string pathinicio, string comando)
    {
        var shell = (WshShell)Interaction.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
        Application.DoEvents();
        shell.CurrentDirectory = pathinicio;

        var exec = shell.Exec("%comspec% /c" + comando);
        string str3 = exec.StdOut.ReadAll();

        string str2 = exec.StdErr.ReadAll();

        if (str2 == "")
        {
            str2 = "=> PROCESO REALIZADO CORRECTAMENTE, EL ARCHIVO SE GENERO EN EL DIRECTORIO SELECCIONADO";
        }

        string str = str2 + str3;
        Application.DoEvents();
        return str;
    }


private void btnC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str;
        string[] strArray;

        strArray = new string[] { "https://", this.txtServidor.Text, "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc" };
        str = string.Concat(strArray);

        if (this.fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string pathinicio = Application.StartupPath + @"\dll\";
            Interaction.MsgBox("La clase sera generada en el directorio seleccionado. (No cierre la ventana emergente)",
                MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Zenith");
            this.txtResultado.Text = this.Ejecutar_Dos(pathinicio, "CrmSvcUtil.exe  /url:" + str + "/out:" + "MSCRM_Entidades.cs" +
                                                                   " /username:" + this.txtUsuario.Text + " /password:" + this.txtContraseña.Text);
        }
    }
```

Lo que me debería dar es esto(es un resultado cuando lo genero por cmd):

```
CrmSvcUtil.exe /url:http://xx.api.crm2.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc  
/out:Usuario.cs /username:admin@ma.cl /password:tete.01$
```

Comment: pero se genera el archivo `Usuario.cs` con el codigo del servicio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas hacer uso del `WScript.Shell` para ejecutar un comando, puedes usar directamente el  `Process.Start()`

Algo como ser

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CrmSvcUtil.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = "/url:http://xx.api.crm2.dynamics.com/XRMService/2011/Organization.svc/out:Usuario.cs /username:admin@ma.cl /password:tete.01$";

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Tienes las propiedades

[ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror?view=netframework-4.5)

[ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput?view=netframework-4.5)

Si necesitas obtener la salida de la consola

Igualmente si analizamos el codigo estas leyendo el `StdOut` y `StdErr`, que serian las salidas en consola estandar y la de errores.

Te muestra el mensaje porque al evalue `StdErr` (el cual asignas a `str2`) esta esta vacia, lo cual indica que no hya ninguna error.

Despues evaluas `StdOut` (el cual asignas a `str3`)  y lo unes al string de `StdErr`, pero la respuesta que obtienes parece ser la correcta

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, aunque la linea que pusiste startInfo.Arguments = "/url:http://xx.api.crm2.dynamics.com/XRMService/2011/Organization.svc/out:Usuario.cs /username:admin@ma.cl /password:tete.01$"; es la que quiero que me genere automáticamente, me explico al generar el boton me tiene que generar una entidad, esta entidad es la sgte (el codigo del boton) this.txtResultado.Text = this.Ejecutar_Dos(pathinicio, "CrmSvcUtil.exe  /url:" + str + "/out:" + "MSCRM_Entidades.cs" +" /username:" + this.txtUsuario.Text + " /password:" + this.txtContraseña.Text);,

Comment: y eso quiero que me lo genere automaticamente, porque yo lo se generar por comando, pero me quiero ahorrar ese proceso y hacerlo automaticamente, disculpa si te molesto con la ayuda, pero no logro sacar el resultado

Comment: pero armar los argumento es simplemente armar una cadena string reemplazando los valores, si tienes los datos simplemente usas `string.Format("/url:{0} /username:{1}", url, username);` puse solo dos valores pero sigue igual con el resto, reemplazas y listo. Si el comando `CrmSvcUtil` requiere eso parametro magicamente no van a inventarse, en algun lado debes configurarlos, quizas de un `app.config` y tomarlos por configuracion para que no queden fijos en el codigo